# Inserting a table in email, only displays table syntax eg. <table><th>

Tags: c#, html, .net, outlook

I am trying to insert a table in email but it only shows the syntax on the message body of the email.

Attached is the output; 
[image]

```
mail.Subject = "Blah Service Alert - " + application + " Upgrade (Day, Month, Year)";
mail.Body = "Dear Customer," + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +

   "I would like to provide notice that we will be carrying out an Upgrade on the " + application + " on (Day, Month, Year)." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +

   "Blah Essential Maintenance Downtime Window 2019" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +

   "System: " + application + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +

   "<table><tr>" +
   "<th> Downtime Start </th>" +
   "<th> Downtime Start </th>" +
   "<th> Downtime End </th>" +
   "<th> Downtime End </th>" +
   "</tr> <tr>" +
   "<td> Date: </td" +
   "<td> Time: </td>" +
   "<td> Date: </td>" +
   "<td> Time: </td>" +
   "</tr></table>" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
```

Comment: Mail message objects usually have a way to specify if the body is html or plain text. See if you can make it html.

Comment: Will try to specify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Outlook Object Model, set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property rather than the plain text `MailItem.Body`.

Comment: It works! But the table doesnt display any border of the cell even tho I included a style

Comment: You really need to show your code and the resulting HTML. You can also compare it with the HTML produced by Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?view=netframework-4.7.2) to true, assuming that you're using [MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.